# Using XSLT from within an IBM Content Navigator plugin

Tags: java, xslt, ibm-content-navigator

I have a plugin for IBM Content Navigator where a user will send a request to the server, and the server will then apply an XSLT transform on an XML file stored in FileNet.

I also use the same code in a stand alone Java application so that an admin can also apply the XSLT without using the ICN interface.

I am trying to place the XSLT inside my plugin Jar file, and read using:

```
InputStream xslt = java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("removeStamp.xslt");
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource( xslt));
```

This works for the Java stand alone application, but not for the ICN Plugin.

How can I use an XSLT from within an IBM Content Navigator plugin jar?

Comment: I believe that you mean it fails as the xslt always returns null (because the resource cannot be found using the class loader), right?

Comment: Yes correct. I'm going to try out your answer now and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this happens due to that the resource is not found, usually you can find the resource:

If within the same package

```
InputStream is = <your class name>.class.getResourceAsStream("removeStamp.xslt");
```

How you are searching makes it look for the file in the root of the classpath. to do so you could use

InputStream is = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/domain/appname/removeStamp.xslt");

The nuclear option is to add the file in the VM classpath root directory (which is not good, but it would work)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, your answer helped me to actually understand what was going on in loading the resource.